# How to get major appengine issues fixed?

Tags: google-app-engine, redirect, https, pagespeed

Hi fellow appengine developers,

we have a major impact issue on an european bank application, which is their first Google Apps and Google Cloud experience. We'd need this to be addressed to keep the trust that Google can provide the service. Is there any option to get such a major issues fixed in a reasonable time? Preferably other than paying for a premier account, which is not needed for this pilot product at this time.

The issue was already reported on appengine public issue tracker for over a month: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7979

App Engine returns 403 on http://customdomain.example.com, instead of redirecting it to https, when secure:always is set in app.yaml. Authentication for the application is set to Google Apps domain, which may (or may not) play role in triggering the issue.

- http://appid.appspot.com redirects correctly to https://appid.appspot.com
- http://customdomain.example.com -> returns 403
- https://customdomain.example.com -> works

Thanks for a beautifully designed service otherwise

Jan

**Update:**

The issue has proven link to Google Page Speed service. Whan disabled in application console, the redirect works ok. When re-enabled, it fails again.

The issue is **observed** on production application with PageSpeed, **VIP SSL**, Google Apps domain authorization, Google Apps data set to store in **EU** Data Centers only.

The issue is **not observed** on testing application with PageSpeed, **SNI SSL**, Google Apps domain authorization, without EU data location restriction.

As a temporary workaround, we commented out *secure:always* for the site entry url's in *app.yaml*, and decorated their handler methods with https://gist.github.com/3974365.

There's also google group discussion, if you have similar issue, or look for solution.
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/w3aKx9KxYoU/discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help, until the issue is fixed. In webapp2 you can restrict URI schemes. This means: when you allow http and https, you can define two routes for http and https and redirect to https if http was chosen.

Webapp2: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#restricting-uri-schemes

Comment: Yep, actually I did not modify the routes, just commented out secure:always for entry points in app.yaml and decorated the target handler methods with https://gist.github.com/3974365


Thanks for your help.